# inner join with another inner join query Between

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

### in English

I have this problem

these are my tables

tableA, B and C

[enter link description here](http://sgp.sytes.net/d.jpg)

I have a art_clie in tableA and TableB field name cli_id another, with which I make an inner join, then the field in TableB cli_pven try with a BETWEEN niv_inic and niv_fina fields TableC

I work only when the value of this cli_pven intervals between 1 and 50
if the intervals are not shown me greater results.
that suecede?
I hope you can help

this is my query code in a stored process:

```
SELECT *,  tablaC.`niv_nimg`
FROM tablaA INNER JOIN  (
    tablaB LEFT JOIN tablaC
        ON tablaB.`cli_pven` BETWEEN tablaC.`niv_inic` AND tablaC.`niv_fina`
) ON tablaA.`art_clie` = tablaB.`cli_id`;
```

### in Spanish

edito para la versión en español:

inner join en otro inner join con consulta de between

en  tablaA tengo un campo art_clie y en la tablaB otro de nombre cli_id, con los cuales hago un inner join, luego con el campo cli_pven de la tablaB intente hacer un between con los campos niv_inic y niv_fina de la tablaC

me funciona solo cuando el valor de cli_pven esta entre los intervalos de 1 y 50
si el valos es mayor no me muestra resultados.
que suecede?
espero puedan ayudarme

este es mi codigo de consulta en un proceso almacenado:

el codigo corregido seria asi:

```
SELECT *,  tablaC.`niv_nimg`
FROM tablaA INNER JOIN  (
    tablaB LEFT JOIN tablaC
        ON tablaB.`cli_pven` BETWEEN tablaC.`niv_inic` AND tablaC.`niv_fina`
) ON tablaA.`art_clie` = tablaB.`cli_id`;
```

Comment: I would love to help, but I'm struggling to make sense of your question and issue. Could you please clear up some spelling mistakes and add clarity? Thanks

Comment: can you show us the sample output?

Comment: good about that is that I do not have fluent English language is basically a translation of google, but if you can speak Spanish would be much better

Comment: You can `JOIN` as much as you like without using `()` for those. `SELECT *, tablaC.niv_nimg FROM tablaA INNER JOIN tablaB ON tablaA.art_clie = tablaB.cli_id LEFT JOIN tablaC ON tablaB.cli_pven BETWEEN tablaC.niv_inic AND tablaC.niv_fina;`

Comment: works but it happens that only works with the first record of the TableC
when the value is greater than 50 cli_pven it does not work
see table records in the link I put in the publication
español
funciona pero sucede que solo funciona con el primer registro de la tablaC
cuando el valor de cli_pven es mayor a 50 entonces no funciona 
ver los registros de la tabla en el vinculo que puse en la publicacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I THINK I have it, and will try to simplify since English is only from translation.

You have TableA is a collection of Art (drawings, pictures, etc) for each client.
TableC has image names (a.png, b.png, c.png, etc) based on a range of values (niv_inic and niv_fina ).  Based on the value in TableB.cli_pven, you want the record that relates to the qualifying range record.

To simplify readability of the query, I am using ALIAS names for the tables as I believe you just changed the names for simple sample purposes of this post.

```
select
      a.*,  
      c.niv_nimg
   from
      TablaA a
         JOIN TablaB b
            on a.art_clie = b.cli_id
            LEFT JOIN TablaC c
               on b.cli_pven BETWEEN c.niv_inic AND c.niv_fina
```

Notice the simple layering of the joining between tables a -> b, then b -> c.

I think you over complicated it with the extra parenthesis causing a bad query syntax
Now, the only time that the image name should come back blank is for any "cli_prev" value that is less than 1, or greater than 250, the max range of TablaC.

I actually made it a LEFT-JOIN instead of just "JOIN" (inner join) to allow you to CONFIRM that you are getting all rows possible and that they should or should not be a match image returned.  You can always change it back to "JOIN" when you are ready.

Comment: ok, it worked. was my mistake, what I needed was to work with equal data. what happens is that my field was cli_pven as varchar, I did so by technical issues but change it to int, as well as fields and niv_fina niv_inic and it worked. I thank you all for participating in my help. is really important to me.
ok, funciono. era mi error, lo que necesitaba era trabajar con igualdad de datos. lo que sucede es que mi campo cli_pven estaba como varchar, lo hice asi por cuestiones tecnicas pero lo cambie a int, asi como los campos de niv_inic y niv_fina y funciono. doy las gracias a todos ayudarme.